# Hidden rows not hidden after copy paste in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

I am copying contents of an excel workbook to another workbook.My sheet has few hidden rows which has to be kept hidden in the target workbook as well.
I am using the below lines of code to copy the data :

```
'Set rngCopyRange = wbSource.ActiveSheet.Cells
rngCopyRange.Copy
```

This works fine in Win 10 64 bit,Office 2013 64bit or Office 2016 32 bit combination
But in windows 10 64b , Office 2010 32b or 2013 32b combination,the hidden rows are not hidden.
Is this an issue with excel version?Can someboby help me to sort this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How odd. I'm using 2013(64bit) and if I use your code I DO NOT copy across the hidden property of each row to the target.

I think the issue you're getting though is that you're copying across a range that doesn't extend across all columns, so setting the row height (i.e. for all columns) would be counter-intuitive.

If you add `.EntireRow` to your copy range, the row height will come across:

```
Set rngCopyRange = wbSource.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow
```

Comment: 'Set rngCopyRange = wbSource.ActiveSheet.Cells

Comment: Did you try as per my answer? `Set rngCopyRange = wbSource.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow`

Comment: Thank you  :-)  I used Set rngCopyRange = wbSource.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow and it is working fine

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answered if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> In 99%* of the cases where people hide rows and then copy and paste
>   them to another location they don't actually need the hidden rows to
>   exist in the destination

... so I'm taking a punt and offering this as a solution:

```
rngCopyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

<sub>*Like all good statistics, I made this one up</sub>

Comment: Wouldn't that just ignore the hidden rows on source, rather than copy but hide them?

Comment: @CLR I'm reading between the lines, but agree it's a good point -- some clarification from OP would be good. Otherwise there's significantly more code required.

Comment: I'm using 2013(64) so I can't recreate this. Can anyone else confirm this is normal behaviour for 2010(32) and/or 2013(32)?

Comment: @CLR I can recreate in 2013(32)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a speculation, but if you are using `wbSource.ActiveSheet.Cells`, aren't you copying **all** the cells in that worksheet, including the *hidden* ones ? Maybe the logic is a bit different for the Office versions, though I still new to VBA.