# Copy and paste only visible rows in Excel - to a new file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a current routine in a workbook which has many sheets, all of which are doing some calcs and referencing each other. On the press of a command button, the user can export the contents of a hidden sheet in to a new file for use later.

This is a work thing so can't share the file but I've created a base file which will simulate the actual problem I have. The pasting takes account of all formatting and removes all links to the original file and data. Files are here :
Main file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Uzq-2_W-hFy4OSHhEXS1WaSADsJWcX4/view?usp=sharing
Output file :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pOWTN1jmOn66ohbuD7xJ0p2JEXm7GMG1/view?usp=sharing

My issue right now is that in the calculations I mentioned above, I've created some VBA which hide rows based on those calculated values. I only want to copy the visible rows in to this new destination file. The original will have some formatting like merged cells which needs to also be carried across.

In the file attached, the data to copy starts at B3 and ends at E14, with row 10 hidden. The code I use now is below - however you can still unhide row 10 if you wish, and I don't want row 10 copied across.

Is there anyway that this is possible? I've tried many methods from this resource and others - all without sucess.

Thanks

```
Sub Copy_Test_data()

Sheets("Test Data").Cells.Copy
Sheets.Add.Name = "New data"
Sheets("Test Data").Visible = False
Sheets("New Data").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Data").Move
Dim fname
fname = InputBox("Enter Revision number")
fname = fname & " New Revision Data.xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fname, FileFormat:=52
Dim ExternalLinksArray As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim x As Long
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
ExternalLinksArray = wb.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
If IsEmpty(ExternalLinksArray) = False Then
For x = 1 To UBound(ExternalLinksArray)
  wb.BreakLink Name:=ExternalLinksArray(x), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
Next x

End If
    

End Sub
```

Comment: Sheets("Test Data").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488892/hidden-rows-not-hidden-after-copy-paste-in-excel